# PHP register form not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a simple user registration form and external connection script with some strange results.
The page register.php shows the form fine, however seems to display my entire connection string before the form?
It then throws up errors in relation to my connection variable '$dbcon' (I have commented the line at which this happens) Here is my register.php code:

```
     <?php
      session_start();
      require "connect.php";

      if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header("location: members.php");
       }

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
      {
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      $rpass = $_POST['rpass'];
      $fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $lname = $_POST['lname'];

if ($user == "" || $pass == "" || $rpass == "") 
{
echo "Please fill all fields";
}

else 
{
 if ($pass != $rpass)
 {
    echo "Passwords do not match";
 }
 else
 {
    //This is where the errors are found
       $query = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user' ") or die ("Cannot query table");

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($row == 1)
    {
        echo "This username is already taken";
    }
    else
    {
    $add = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, username,                                                   password, admin) VALUES
    (null, '$fname', '$lname', '$user', '$pass', '$admin') ") or die ("Cant insert data");
    echo "Successfully added user!";
    }
 }
}
    }
    ?>
```

And here is my connection file 'connect.php' (the $dbcon string is the one that prints out??)

```
  $server = 'localhost';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $dbname = 'bodgett';

  $dbcon = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname)or die("Can not connect to Server.");
```

Specifically, the error is 'Notice: Undefined variable: dbcon in C:\webserver...\register2.php'
Can anyone suggest why is doesn't recognize this variable?

Comment: Probabbly wrong filename (file isn't called connect.php), Because i just copied all your code, and its working for me. He finds the variable $dbcon

Comment: I have already solved it haha! my connect.php was not enclosed as a php script, back to school for me

Comment: Lol, I thought you didn't copy that with your code.. :D But was just writing that as an answer with some idfferent things.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a wrong filename (maybe file isn't called connect.php) OR wrong file extension? (html instead of .php)

I just copied all your code, and it works for me. Aswell I don't see php start and closing Tags.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Xatenev. Also, you may want to consider using PDO for your database interactions, it's the most secure way. I found this very helpful: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Sorry if this seems irrelevant, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mysqli extension is enabled

the code that generates $dbcon is inside a class or inside some function? 
If yes, maybe you need to return or call it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The connection file 'connect.php' is not enclosed within  tags, hence not usable and explains why the text was simply printing out at the top of the page.